# Embedded Google Spreadsheet resets website's scroll position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-sheets

I am writing a web application in AngularJS, which uses embedded google spreadsheet.

My app has horizontal layout, and the spreadsheet is aligned to right. It is extending over the browsers right edge, which is fine. Scrolling left and right works as expected.

The problem is that every mouse event that is related to google spreadsheet causes website's scroll position reset back to initial (0, 0). E.g. User clicks any cell; user chooses some menu action; user scrolls down spreadsheet's worksheet.

Do you have any idea how to prevent it or what could be the cause? I would greatly appreciate if you could help me.

Thank you in advance.